# Find the Codeunit for a Function

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I need to know how to find the codeunit that is being called when I click on Actions->Functions-> Create Job Sales Invoice on the Jobs page - page 89.  How can I tell what codeunit is being called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to figure that out is to enable the Event Recorder, then perform your action and then stop the Event Recorder.

All events that were fired during the process will then be listed and you should be able to determine which codeunits were involved.

The Event Recorder can be started from the web client.

Hit Alt+Q then search for Event Recorder.